# UIStoryboardSegue & UIVisualEffectView - Blur effect lost after completion block exits

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a small application that consist of a view controller with an UIImageView. When the user taps the screen a tableview controller is presented (model) with a custom transition. The transition adds a UIBlurEffectview to the presented tableview. The desired effect is to display the UITableView over the blurred image.

When the tableview is presented it shows the blur view for a split second. However, once the completion block exits (on presentViewController:animated:completion) the view goes fully black.

Example before completion block exits:
[image]

After the completion block exits:
[image]

Here is the segue code:

```
UIViewController *sourceController = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destinationController  = self.destinationViewController;


UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blurView.frame = destinationController.view.frame;


[destinationController.view setOpaque:NO];
[destinationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[destinationController.view insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0];
[destinationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

[sourceController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed");
}];
```

I am sort of stuck on where to go.I know the last call before the completion block is called is viewDidAppear on the presented controller, and thats not changing anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. If you're using Modal segue then you need to set the Presentation from default to full screen.

Comment: i got this working but now the funny part is the unwind segue does not animate my source view controller :(